# Rails: redirect_to '#{user.role}_url' how do I accomplish this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way in rails/ruby to simplify my routing code to be elegant like:

redirect_to user.role + _url

This way if the user is an admin they will be routed to the admin page so on so forth for other user types...

Comment: Note, I added an explanation of what is going on and why your approach wasn't working to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Sure!***

```
redirect_to send("#{user.role}_url")
```

in ruby, the send will execute the method on the receiver, and that's exactly what you want. Usually, that would look like:

```
@receiver_object.send(:admin_url)
```

But the url-helpers work in the global namespace, so you can send to global and have it work.

**Easy way to test**: Add this to a controller and watch it redirect you home:

```
redirect_to send("root_path")
```

Comment: awesome, the send() method is what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way would be to use the [url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for) helper. For example.

```
redirect_to url_for( :controller => users, :action => user.role )
```

This would generate a path `/users/admin` or `/users/guest` etc.

If you want to do it a hackish way you could use

```
redirect_to eval("#{user.role}_url")
```

Be careful with that though. The reason your string isn't working is it isn't evaluated, so `redirect_to "admin_url"` doesn't do anything, it's just a meaningless string and redirect is expecting the string to be a URL.

If you evaluate the string it would work, because `redirect_to eval("#{user.role}_url")` is going to first convert `"admin_url"` into calling the `admin_url` method, which returns some path like `users/admin`, and THAT string is useable by the redirect method.

Comment: cool, looks like send and eval both work for my purposes! I would upvote but Im so new I can't

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render "#{user.role}"`. Just be sure to have corresponding views with the names admin.html.erb' and so on.

Comment: I really think redirect_to is more appropriate here. It seems like he's conceptually going to a new page with a new URL.

Comment: I tried this but it resulted in a connection drop like when I tried to do what is in the title and my question. Is there a better way to do it when I have views/admin/index.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you could do, but nothing built in and nothing that would be significantly simpler than `send("#{user.role}_url")`. Be sure to use send() - otherwise it will redirect to the URL "/admin_url" instead of calling the admin_url helper.

One such other solution would be to create an action called 'home' that would redirect to the current_user's role's page. That would add an extra redirect (slightly increase the page load time), but it would make your redirects simpler

```
redirect_to home_url
```

Comment: unfortunately redirect_to "#{user.role}_url" doesn't work for me for some reason, it just drops the connection every time I try that. any ideas as to why it's doing that?

Comment: Because you're passing the string "admin_url" not the method `admin_url` which gets evaluated into the string `users/admin`.

Comment: Try send("#{user.role}_url") instead. Otherwise it'll redirect to "/admin_url", which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Andrew's answer, but you could also do something like

```
redirect_to send(user.role.to_s + '_url')
```

Comment: you're right too of course, the send part is what I was missing.